# Need some help on MAUI binding in collection view

Tags: binding, maui, collectionview

I need some help on binding in a TapGestureRecognizer. I have the following code where I create a CollectionView. I create a TapGestureRecognizer in that view and would like the command parameter to the object in the list itself. I can't seem to figure out a way to word the binding in the command parameter to make this happen. I worked around it for the time being by setting the selection mode and using the bound value of "SelectedObject". Ideally, I would like the commandparameter to be the object in the list itself.

Thanks.

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="switchCollection"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ShopSwitches}"
                    ItemsLayout="HorizontalGrid, 4"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSwitch,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1">
        <CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Command="{Binding OnSwitchTappedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type BindableObject}}}"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="2"/>
        </CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
```

`.` represents the current object

Comment: That binds to the viewmodel not the actual object that was tapped. Seems like it's close but not exactly what I am looking for. I'd like the command parameter to be the actual object in the collection not the viewModel. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That’s because your gesture is attached to the entire view, not the individual rows

Comment: This is perfect, thanks much for the help. I thought I tried the gestures on the grid but must have missed something. Working like a champ now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said that your gesture is attached to the entire view, not the individual rows, take the following code as an example, you can add gesture on Grid:

```xml
<ContentPage ....
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModels">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:viewmodels/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Habits}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:viewmodels}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
   </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public partial class viewmodels
{
    ....
    
    public Command TapCommand { get; }
    
    public viewmodels () 
    { 
        TapCommand = new Command<object> (OnTap); 
        
        ....
    }

    private void OnTap (object obj)
    {
        var h = obj as Habit;
        Console.WriteLine (h.Name);
    }
    
    ....
}
```

When you tap the item of collectionview, console will print `Name` of the item. And here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/jgY3RD4).